# Rainbow animated text jQuery destroying innerHTML

Tags: jquery

I have a simple markup

```
<a href="/u1"><span style="color:#FF0000"><strong>Mr.EasyBB</strong></span></a>
```

This is the jQuery caller for the API Rainbow

```
$('a[href="/u1"]').rainbow({ 
colors: [
    '#FF0000',
    '#f26522',
    '#fff200',
    '#00a651',
    '#28abe2',
    '#2e3192',
    '#6868ff'
],
animate: true,
animateInterval: 100,
pad: false,
pauseLength: 100,
});
```

Though whenever I make it go it shows the HTML as the link. To better understand please visit the jsfiddle I have provided since this is so strange!

http://jsfiddle.net/sr5df/

If someone knows of a fix please help me out here, this is just mind boggling.
​

Comment: I feel like I've just been rick-rolled... Hilarious plugin.

Comment: Why hilarious? lol. I use it for my members, they want codes to make their members names "animate rainbow/chrome/lightscroll" Some are girls so you know how they like it pretty.

Comment: When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, please mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. If you need more clarification do not hesitate to ask =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin uses the innerHTML of the wrapped set's elements. If you target the tag surrounding the actual text that you want to animate then you're good. So use this call instead:

```
$('a[href="/u1"] strong')... etc
```

Answer (score 3):

replace

```
options.originalText = $(this).html();
```

with

```
options.originalText = $(this).text();
```

Comment: And a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sr5df/9/). =) This does, however, have the problem that it removes the `strong` tags (so if they're essential you'll need to target that element instead of the parent `a`).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZYJ9r/2/   (I just changed line #4 and added a strong tag as suggested by @koenp and @DavidThomas)

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear, sorry: I was *offering* a link, not requesting one. =)

Comment: Ahh I see that now thank you. I may have to use the actual target since This is not specifically for me it is for members of my site.